# Assigning new value to a string - C

Tags: c, string, char, variable-assignment

Trying to take in several file names from the user at the command line and store them into a linked list, but I'm receiving a segmentation fault. The idea is to have the user enter each file name then enter 'q' when they're finished.

I enter in the first file name, "man_on_moon.txt" and no error occurs. After I enter the second, "sat_moons_rings.txt" I get.. Segmentation fault: 11
I believe it's occurring in my assignment to char *name, but am not sure.

```
char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) *50);
scanf("%s", name);
list *curr, *head;
curr = malloc(sizeof(list));
head = malloc(sizeof(head));
if(name != "q")
{
    curr->item = name;
    head->next = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
    scanf("%s", name);
}
while(name != "q")
{
    curr->item = name;
    curr = curr->next;
    scanf("%s", name);
}
```

Comment: You are only allocating one string.  Every time you do `scanf("%s", name)`, you will overwrite the same string data.

Comment: THis line is a little fishy: "`head = malloc(sizeof(head));`" Maybe just a typo, but `head` and `curr` are the same type pointer, but they're being assigned different sized blocks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set `curr->next` to anything so it's pointing to `NULL` then you set `curr` to `curr->next`. Therefore when you get into the while loop you access `curr->item` you are trying to get the fields of `NULL` and you get a segfault.

The reason behind this is you are only mallocing space for 2 nodes. You have malloc space for every node you make.

Comment: Great, I've allocated memory for each curr->next that occurs and the program accepts multiple file names. Thank you. However, it does not exit the while loop, when I enter q into the command line. Suggestions?

Comment: don't use `!=` use `strcmp(name, "q") != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You should limit the scanf string so it can't overflow your buffer:

```
scanf("%49s", Name);
```

Then, to compare the end of your loop you need to check with the character - not a string comparison:

```
if (name[0] != 'q')
```

..

Finally, you need to copy your name in to your list as well.

Comment: you shouldn't use `if(name[0] != 'q')` because that will break for any string that starts with 'q' as well as the string "q"

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Wrote that answer too quickly. It should have a strlen(name) == 1 added, or just strcmp() as you mentioned.